# Highlight UILabel in Table

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uilabel

In my `UITableView` I am having different controls like `UIImage`, `UILabel`... When I click a `UILabel`, color of the text has to be highlighted. Can anyone help me please?. This is the below code.

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer* gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(UserNameClick:)];
    [cell.usrName setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [cell.usrName addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
    cell.usrName.tag=indexPath.row;



   - (IBAction)UserNameClick:(id)sender
   {
      UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;
      NSString *strUserID,*strUsername;
      NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.allPostArray objectAtIndex:[tapRecognizer.view tag]];
   }
```

Comment: To show changes in UITableView elements you have to reload tableview. So you have to set label color changes in "cellForRowAtIndexPath" and you have to save last selected / current selected index also to get required change in tableview..

Comment: You can do also without tapgesture

Comment: i also posted my working demo application code for you

Comment: Subramanian Raj Put button on tableview and change background color when click on button or cell ..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where exactly you are doing mistake?. But use below code you can get answer.

```
   First create 
          UILabel *label;

   UITapGestureRecognizer* gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(UserNameClick:)];
   gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
   [cell.usrName setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
   [cell.usrName addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
   cell.usrName.tag=indexPath.row;
   //Assign cell.usrName to label
   label = cell.usrName;

   - (IBAction)UserNameClick:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender
   {
      NSString *strUserID,*strUsername;
      label.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
      NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.allPostArray objectAtIndex:[sender.view tag]];
   }

 You have to set gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
```

Comment: - (IBAction)UserNameClick:(id)sender in this function we have to change the color of cell.usrName label... I don't know how to do that

Comment: tapping is working for the label, there is no problem in it, my problem is, when the user taps the label, the label text has to be highlighted in red color

Comment: Now do you want to change the text color in red color?

Comment: Label or Label Text Color in red color?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85099/discussion-between-user3182143-and-subramanian-raj).

Comment: The label is inside the custom table cell. so we can't use Label.textColor as you had mentioned, I feel it has to be done through sender but I don't know how to do it :(

Comment: Please create UILabel *label in .h and assign cell.usrLabel to this label.Because once you set the tag automatically it assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 - (IBAction)UserNameClick:(id)sender
 {
   UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;
   NSString *strUserID,*strUsername;
   NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.allPostArray objectAtIndex:[tapRecognizer.view tag]];
   //your custom cell object 
   UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender.superview.superview;
   cell.label.textColor = your color; 
 }
```

Comment: In the UITableView there will be more cells, by your method, we won't know in which tablecell the label text has to be highlighted.

Comment: you can give tag to each cell and check which cell is that..!

Comment: @RahulShirphule apple in session 231 "Cocoa touch best practices" from WWDC 2015 recommends to NOT use view tagging :)

Comment: in that case you can use isKindOfClass on cell Object and then change color of Label

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might be helpful for others... to highlight the UILabel in TabelCell we have to do like this

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
{
   if (highlighted) {
     self.usrName.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
   } else {
     self.usrName.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set Starting Values for last selected / current selected index

```
self.prvSelectedIndex = -1;
    self.currentSelectedIndex = 0;
```

Modify cellForRowAtIndexPath like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MyTableViewCell";

```
MyTableViewCell *cell = (MyTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

//    DataSourceModel* dbObject = (DataSourceModel*)[self.arrayDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.myCellLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.arrayDataSource[indexPath.row]];
    int indexed = (int)indexPath.row;
    cell.myCellLabel.tag = indexed+1;

```
cell.myCellLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
if (indexed==self.currentSelectedIndex) {
    cell.myCellLabel= (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:indexed+1];
    cell.myCellLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

return cell;
```

}

Update last and previous selected index

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

if (self.prvSelectedIndex!=indexPath.row) {
    self.prvSelectedIndex = self.currentSelectedIndex=(int)indexPath.row;
    self.currentSelectedIndex = (int)indexPath.row;
    [self.refWeakTableView reloadData];
}
```

}